# internal anchor links no longer working after upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my website [www.ownscene.com](http://www.ownscene.com).

You can see the main button on the top, when mouse hover browser says it anchor to `#port` but when I click nothing happened. This happened after multiple WordPress upgrades (I didn't check how the previous versions behaved).

Happen with plan text `<a href>` as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately the problem you're describing is not one inherent to or commonly seen in vanilla WordPress, and based on the information provided here alone it is not possible to provide and definitive answer to this question, which likely means it does not fit the Q&A format of our site. That said, a hashlink like `#port` is usually directing a visitor to an HTML element with the `id` attribute of `port`, which does not appear to exist on the linked page. It is impossible for anyone here to say if it should exist and why it no longer does.

Comment: Problem is if you go to www.ownscene.com/#port it correctly takes you there but the anchor doesn't work at all. Sorry for missing this information.

Comment: Ah I see it now - I overlooked it earlier, somehow. Looks like there's a click handler on that button from `/wp-content/themes/x/framework/js/dist/site/x-body.min.js` which is intercepting and killing that event. Specifically, the one beginning with `t('a[href*="#"]').on("touchstart click"`. When I detach the handler clicking the link appropriately jumps to the respective section. Sounds like you might need to contact the `x` theme's support channels

Comment: Actually it looks like that code is intended to replace the default "jump to" behavior with a smooth easing transition to it. The function which it's using to call `jQuery.fn.animate()` relies on two variables which are undefined, resulting in the animation failing. Since the scripts are minified it's not clear what those variables were supposed to contain, or where those values were supposed to be set

Comment: Thank you, I removed that line and it worked!.... and then the menu broke! ok I should contact theme support